# Wrong behavior in concatenation of strings when allignment of component is "RIGHT_TO_LEFT"

Tags: java, jtextfield, calculator, right-align

```
private JTextField resultTextField = new JTextField("0");
resultTextField.setFont(textFieldFont);
        resultTextField.setBounds(COMMON_X, COMMON_Y, 180, 50);
        resultTextField.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        add(resultTextField);
```

I have created a JTextField as above.My application consists of number buttons and '.'. When I click on number buttons they get appended right (i.e. **"5"** on 5 click and then **"52"** on 2 click). But on clicking the **'.'** button the expected result is **"5."** but the it is displayed as **".5"** and then on clicking **"2" , "5.2**" is displayed.
Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: A perfect case for an SSCCE -- I suggest you make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing (from your tags) that you're programming a calculator of some sort and that you want to achieve right-*aligned* text, not right-to-left-*oriented* text.
Right-to-left orientation is used for e.g. arabic languages, which are written (you guessed it) from right to left, instead of the "western" way of writing from left to right.

I suggest you remove the `applyComponentOrientation()` and look at [setHorizontalAlignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29) instead.

PS: that being said, I can't really tell why '5'+'.' is '.5', but '5'+'.'+'2' is displayed as '5.2'.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem but the above question remains.

Answer (score 1):

I got interested, and produced the following SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class BasicFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BasicFrame frame = new BasicFrame();
        frame.go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        JTextField resultTextField = new JTextField("0");
        resultTextField.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        add(resultTextField);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

So now I have the same question: If I clear the field and enter "123", it appears as "123"; when I click the period key (either of them), the field then shows ".123"; if I then enter "abc", the field shows "123.abc"; the period jumps to the right of the displayed string when I enter the 'a'.  This does not follow what a former boss of mine called the "principle of least atstonishment"...

Comment: It exhibits the same behaviour for other punctuation -- comma, exclamation, etc.

Comment: Ok, after a (really short) google session I assume it has something to do with arabic *numbers* being read left-to-right, while text is right-to-left. I.e. "15 days" right-to-left should be printed as "syad 15" (at least that's what I'm guessing). But to me that still doesn't explain why punctuation jumps around the number. Internationalization is just messy ;)

Comment: But only punctuation jumps around, text and numbers behave the same as each other.  I'm wondering if it isn't something about a right-to-left component and a left-to-right character set.  I don't know anything about right-to-left text.